# Media Foundation how to retrieve multiple video renerers from EVR

Tags: video, ms-media-foundation

In my application I have two video renderers added in the EVR using.

```
hr = MFCreateVideoRendererActivate(hVideoWindow, &pActivate);
```

When topology status is changed I call:

```
if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && (status == MF_TOPOSTATUS_READY))
{
    (void)MFGetService(m_pSession, MR_VIDEO_RENDER_SERVICE, IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_pVideoDisplay));

     ...
```

This video render service represent only one video.
And When I change the video `SetAspectRatioMode` or `SetVideoPosition` then it affect only one video.

How do I retrieve all the video rendrers that are there in the EVR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MediaSession provided by MediaFoundation is not intended to be used with two Video Renderers.

So, with MediaSession, you can't get all video renderers.